# Grouped Tableview From JSON Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I've been following a tutorial on YouTube and trying to expand its functionality.  I figured out how to send the retrieveData method to a background thread using GCD, figured out how to use Reachability to keep the app from crashing when in Airplane Mode, and now I'm trying to change the tableview to a grouped style.  After a couple of weeks I'm at my wit's end.

What I want to do is have the UITableView grouped using the key "country" to establish the groups, and any city within that country appear in the group's cells.  The number of countries in the database will change, as will the number of cities.

I'm not even sure it's possible given the data structure, but if it is, I could use some suggestions.

The JSON data is structured like this:

[{"id":"1","cityName":"London","cityState":"London","cityPopulation":"8173194","country":"United Kingdom"}

Here is the .m file:

```
#import "CitiesViewController.h"
#import "City.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "Reachability.h"

#define getDataUrl @"http://www.conkave.com/iosdemos/json.php"

@interface CitiesViewController ()

@end

@implementation CitiesViewController
@synthesize jsonArray, citiesArray;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

//Set the title of our VC
self.title = @"Cities of the World";

//Load data
[self retrieveData];    

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

// Return the number of rows in the section.
return citiesArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...
City * cityObject;
cityObject = [citiesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = cityObject.cityName;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = cityObject.cityCountry;

//Accessory
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Navigation


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
// Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"pushDetailView"])
{
    NSIndexPath * indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    //Get the object for the selected row
    City * object = [citiesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [[segue destinationViewController] getCity:object];
    }
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Class Methods

- (void) retrieveData;
{

Reachability *networkReachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
NetworkStatus networkStatus = [networkReachability currentReachabilityStatus];
if (networkStatus == NotReachable) {

        UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Internet"
                                                          message:@"You must have an internet connection for this feature"
                                                         delegate:self
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [message show];
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
        return;
    }

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
//Retrieve the data asynchronously
dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataUrl];

    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    //Set up our cities array
    citiesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //Loop through our jsonArray

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.count; i++)
    {
        //Create our city object
        NSString * cID = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"];
        NSString * cName = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"cityName"];
        NSString * cState = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"cityState"];
        NSString * cPopulation = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"cityPopulation"];
        NSString * cCountry = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"country"];

        //Add the city object to our cities array
        [citiesArray addObject:[[City alloc] initWithCityName:cName andCityState:cState andCityCountry:cCountry andcityPopulation:cPopulation andCityID:cID]];


    }
    //Back to main thread to update UI.use dispatch_get_main_queue() to get main thread
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        //Reload our table view
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    });

});

}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group the data yourself pretty easily in a few ways. One way is by using an array for ordering the countries and a dictionary to group the cities within them.

After you are done creating your `City` objects, you can do something like this:

```
// you probably want to save these as instance properties
NSMutableArray *countries = [NSMutableArray new];
NSMutableDictionary *citiesForCountries = [NSMutableDictionary new];

for(City *city in citiesArray)
{
    NSString *currentCountry = city.country;

    NSMutableArray *citiesInCountry = citiesForCountries[@"currentCountry"];
    // first city for this country, so add it to our ordered list and create an array to populate with cities
    if(! citiesInCountry)
    {
        [countries addObject:currentCountry];
        citiesInCountry = [NSMutableArray new];
        citiesForCountries[@"currentCountry"] = citiesInCountry;
    }
    [citiesInCountry addObject:city]; 
}

// Then here are some of the relevant methods on how you would use these data structures
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return countries.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    NSString *country = countries[section];
    NSArray *cities = citiesForCountries[country];
    return cities.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    City * cityObject;

    NSString *country = countries[indexPath.section];
    NSArray *cities = citiesForCountries[country];
    cityObject = cities[indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = cityObject.cityName;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = cityObject.cityCountry;

    //Accessory
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  A couple of questions, though.  You said, "After you are done creating your City objects.."  I'm not sure exactly where you are referring.  City is a class, and the objects are created in the City.h and City.m documents, but it doesn't seem like the right place for the code you posted.  Second, I get warnings about declaring variables locally, and an error that says "country" not found on object of type City.  Sorry if I seem lost - I am.

Comment: The place I am referring to is in your `retrieveData` method right after you finish populating your `citiesArray` array. I came up with that property name myself because you didn't actually post your `City` class so I had no way of knowing what it was. Just swap in the right name you actually used.

Comment: That's what I thought, and what I had done, but when running the program in the simulator it comes up without any table view visible.  The title "Cities of the world is there, then just a gray field below it.  I declared the other instance properties, synthesized them, and added the tableView methods.  In the storyboard I made sure the tableView style was changed to "grouped".  And, I still get warnings about declaring "countries" and citiesForCountries" locally, even though they are declared publicly.